# How to add multiple apple watchkit app for multiple targets single iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, apple-watch, xcode-6.2, ios8.2

I have an iOS application with several targets. I want to create multiple apple watchkit app for different targets in single iPhone app.

EX: iOS application having two targets name like "ABC" and "XYZ". Now I want to add two apple watchkit app for both targets.

Is there an option to do?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit your post to contain your attempts so far and what issues you've encountered.

Comment: When adding a WatchKit app target, the Xcode assistant will ask which iOS app target the new WatchKit app should be associated with.  Just run through the Add Target assistant multiple times, selecting the WatchKit App template and a different iOS app target each time.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the WatchKit target, in he opening window, select the targets you want your WatchKit app and extension to associate with.